# Round up to certain number

Tags: python, rounding

Lets say I have  a list of numbers: `[0.13,0.53,2.83]`
I want these numbers to round UP to the nearest x=0.5 (or any other value for x)
This list would then become, given x=0.5: `[0.5,1,3]`.

I tried somethings with % but neither of what I tried seemed to work.

Any ideas?

Harry

EDIT: the other posts want to know the nearest value, so 1.6 would become 1.5, but in my case it should become 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`math.ceil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil):

```
import math

numbers = [0.13, 0.53, 2.83]
x = 0.5

def roundup(numbers, x):
    return [math.ceil(number / x) * x for number in numbers]

roundup(numbers, x)
# returns [0.5, 1.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: This answer should not have been accepted. For example when x=0.6 then your function returns "number + {0, 0.6 or 1.2}" while I think the expected result is "number + {0, 0.6 or 1}".

Answer (score 0):

If a function suits your need then the function bellow works for positive numbers. "x" is the number you want to round and thresh is the value (between 0 and 1) used to round up.

```
def rounding_function(x, thresh):
    if x == int(x):
        return x
    else:
        float_part = x-int(x)
        if float_part<=thresh:
            return int(x) + thresh
        else:
            return int(x) + 1
```

Which gives the following result:

```
l = [0, 0.13,0.53, 0.61, 2.83, 3]

print([rounding_function(x, 0.5) for x in l]) # [0, 0.5, 1, 1, 3, 3]
print([rounding_function(x, 0.6) for x in l]) # [0, 0.6, 0.6, 1, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general solution. (Don't forget to handle all the "weird input"; e.g. negative `incr`, negative `x`, etc.)

```py
import math

def increment_ceil(x, incr=1):
    """ 
    return the smallest float greater than or equal to x
    that is divisible by incr
    """
    if incr == 0:
        return float(x)
    else:
        return float(math.ceil(x / incr) * incr)
```